# Why doesn't Select-String filter the input of a ToString() method?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, select-string

Why doesn't powershell filter the output of an object's toString method?

```
Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine\my | % { Select-String -InputObject $_.ToString() -Pattern 'testcert' -SimpleMatch }
```

Instead I just get everything I would normally get by running

`Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine\my | % { $_.ToString() }`

I was expecting that like `grep` or `findstring` I would get just the lines that match the regex.

One would think that once `$_.ToString()` is called, you would just get string output...instead, am I just getting objects, or an array of strings?

Comment: i suspect that - at that point - you are NOT looking at a collection of strings. [*grin*] that would mean that you are running against one string at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select-String` works on *individual strings* ... and you are giving it just that - individual multiline strings. [*grin*]

if you want to match a certain string in the properties of the cert, use `Where-Object {$_.PropName -match 'TestValue'}` to get the object that contains the test value in the named prop.

Comment: Oh I forgot about Where-Object...when the output looks like a bunch of text instead of Members, I always want to grep.

Comment: @leeand00 - yep, folks who are accustomed to text parsing really get info a hole when seeing what the _display system_ shows as strings ... but is really a string-ified complex object. i find that frequent use of `.GetType()` is right handy ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Lee_Daily already provided you an answer, but you have also done the following...

```
(Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine\my) -match 'testcert'
```

Example on one of my test machines

```
Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine\my


PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::localmachine\my

Thumbprint    Subject 
----------    ------- 
FEB8E79E06... CN=NVIDIA GameStream Server         
D2D983C386... CN=Windows Admin Center             
96A0413F93... CN=Windows Admin Center             
5299896B41... CN=localhost                        



(Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine\my) -match 'admin'


PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::localmachine\my

Thumbprint    Subject 
----------    ------- 
D2D983C386... CN=Windows Admin Center             
96A0413F93... CN=Windows Admin Center             



(Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine\my) -match 'localhost'


PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::localmachine\my

Thumbprint    Subject 
----------    ------- 
5299896B41... CN=localhost
```